# Alternative to maven assembly:single for packaging

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

What are the alternatives for packaging a standalone java application apart from creating a big fat assembly, which is horrible in some scenarios as

1) Conflicting files (with same names eg. reference.xml) in resource path of two or more jars get overriden by the lucky one.

2) Replacing a single jar is not possible without extracting and merging and compressing again.

Is there a solution more on the lines of an exploded war file, with all the libs in a lib folder and main class file's jar containing manifest entries.
I am sure i had done that in ant and could surely be done in maven too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assembly plugin will be the good choice with a custom descriptor:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <descriptors>
        <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
    </descriptors>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

And in the assembly.xml:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
<id>bin</id>
<formats>
    <format>tar.gz</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>true</includeBaseDirectory>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>/lib</outputDirectory>
        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
        <unpack>false</unpack>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

All the dependencies will be seperate jars in the lib directory next to the project jar file.

Comment: Your provided config file works well except that the project's jar itself doesnt get build into the tar.gz file. FOr which i had to do a jar and include it maually. But this is still the best i got.

Comment: <include>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</include> may not match on your project's jar. It should be changed according to the name of the jar's name.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use [Mojo's AppAssembler Maven Plugin](http://mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) to make a distribution and then use the [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to wrap that all up into a `tar.gz` or `zip` file that comprises the distribution... sometimes I will go further and use [Mojo's Unix Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/unix/) to create `.deb` and `.rpm` installers, and I have heard good things from people who need Windows installers using [Mojo's NSIS Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/nsis-maven-plugin/) though [NPanday's WiX Maven plugin](http://incubator.apache.org/npanday/docs/1.2/plugins/wix-maven-plugin/) should be able to do similar and previously when I needed to generate Windows installers I wrote my own WiX Maven plugin, but the source code for that remains with my previous employers.

If you go down the [AppAssembler](http://mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) route, I would suspect you might prefer a [repositoryLayout](http://mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/assemble-mojo.html#repositoryLayout) of `flat`